# Modificar tabla de rutas de red

Tags: vpn, windows

Necesito que mientras esté conectado a mi VPN únicamente salir por la VPN a un rango de IPs fijas (`192.168.0.x`) y al resto de las IPs accederlas por fuera de la VPN.

Tengo una IP estática asignada (`190.12.113.236`)

Esta es la tabla de rutas actual:

[image: route print]

¿Qué debería modificar? Estuve probando distintas alternativas pero o bien me quedo sin Internet, o siempre termina saliendo por la VPN.

---

**Edición**:

Con esta configuración, por ejemplo, quedo sin Internet:

[image: route print]

Comment: Por lo que veo tu problema es que tienes esta segunda ruta `0.0.0.0` que sale por la VPN con métrica 11, mientras la ruta `0.0.0.0` que sale por fuera de la VPN, pero con métrica 4491. Así las cosas, todo el tráfico va a salir por la VPN.

Comment: intenté cambiarle la métrica de la primer fila a un valor menor pero no hay caso. intenté eliminar la fila de la VPN (y crear una fila para que acceda a la red local) pero me deja sin internet.  con esta configuración por ejemplo me quedo sin internet, cuando yo entiendo que le estoy indicando que salga por la ip 190.12.113.236  http://i.imgur.com/WGp46iS.png un tracert me dice problema de DNS tengo configurado el 8.8.8.8 en dicha interfaz

Comment: luego de conectarte a la vpn puedes eliminar la ruta a internet por la VPN. `route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 190.12.113.233`

Comment: esa ruta es la ip externa, la vpn es 192.168.0.x

Comment: ahi va la direccion del gateway

Comment: eso hice (segunda imagen de mi post) y sigo sin internet. Me dice error de DNS (a pesar que el dns de esa interfaz es 8.8.8.8)

Comment: Vamos por pasos. Ya con una sola ruta `0.0.0.0`, ¿la 8.8.8.8 responde al ping?

Comment: Nadie?????????? T_T

Comment: Disculpen la demora, ya volví a la oficina. Eliminando la 0.0.0.0 y dejando solo la IP pública con el dns 8.8.8.8 no tengo salida a internet, no tengo ping a 8.8.8.8 (Error general). http://imgur.com/qUZX0up

Comment: Error general indica que no hay comunicación por la ruta que se quiere utilizar. Con esa configuración, le haces ping a la 190.12.113.233?

Comment: ah, una recomendación más, cuándo me respondas un comentario, utiliza la notación @usuario para que la persona a quién respondes reciba una notificación. Por suerte me di cuenta de tu respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: asumo que lo que quieres es no salir a traves de internet al conectarte por VPN, pero a su vez no perder conectividad con los equipos que requieres de la red 192.168.0.x antes de darte algunas opciones confirmame exactamente a que recursos de tu red necesitas ingresar por VPN (file server, una aplicación etc... o si te conectas por RDP a servidores o algo asi)

Comment: ¿Qué herramienta usas para crear la VPN? Debería tener una opción para enviar solo el tráfico _interno_ (192.168/16 en tu caso) a través de la VPN.

Comment: Disculpen la demora. La solución fue sacar el checkbox a "usar puerta de enlace predeterminada en la red remota" en la configuración de la VPN.  http://i.imgur.com/BOqoH7F.png Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue quitar el check a "usar puerta de enlace predeterminada en la red remota".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: marcala como respuesta entonces ;)

Comment: @JuanK gracias lo había olvidado